Origin header not sent in Next.js cross-origin requests
I'm fetching an image from a s3 bucket to display in my Next.js app. I get a 403 response due to a Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB). I assume this is because s3 is not sending the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, as it seems to be missing when I check for it in the networks tab on chrome. I think this is happening because for some reason in the request Next.js is not sending a Origin header.
This is my header configuration in the next.config.js file:
const ContentSecurityPolicy = `
  default-src 'self';
  script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' *.googletagmanager.com *.google-analytics.com va.vercel-scripts.com giscus.app vitals.vercel-insights.com *.public.blob.vercel-storage.com;
  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com;
  img-src * blob: data:;
  media-src 'none';
  connect-src *;
  font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com;
  frame-src giscus.app
`

const securityHeaders = [
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP
  {
    key: 'Content-Security-Policy',
    value: ContentSecurityPolicy.replace(/\n/g, ''),
  },
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy
  {
    key: 'Referrer-Policy',
    value: 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin',
  },
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options
  {
    key: 'X-Frame-Options',
    value: 'DENY',
  },
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options
  {
    key: 'X-Content-Type-Options',
    value: 'nosniff',
  },
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-DNS-Prefetch-Control
  {
    key: 'X-DNS-Prefetch-Control',
    value: 'on',
  },
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security
  {
    key: 'Strict-Transport-Security',
    value: 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains',
  },
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Feature-Policy
  {
    key: 'Permissions-Policy',
    value: 'camera=(), microphone=(), geolocation=()',
  },
]

I've tried changing my s3 CORS configuration, but I think it's correct?
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
        ]
    }
]


Don't conflate Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) with Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). Besides, any cross-origin request issued by a browser-based client includes an Origin header; are you sure your request is cross-origin?
